# Намеренное снижение рейтинга конкретному участнику

Tags: обсуждение, репутация, голосование

Недавно под одним из моих ответов провелась небольшая дискуссия с конкретным пользователем. После её окончания он решил **намеренно снизить репутацию** всем моим вопросам, что на человеке с большим их количеством и маленьким рейтингом очень сильно сказывается. В итоге - больше половины моих вопросов, *ранее пребывавшие с нулевым рейтингом*, теперь углубились своей репутацией в минус, заработав для меня запрет на задавание вопросов:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и, что довольно важно - с моим нынешним рейтингом ниже 200 я не смогу получить дополнительный баф репутации от регистрации на других проектах. Считается ли это **нарушением** или, хотя бы, дурным тоном со стороны пользователя?

Comment: 19 числа система откатывала голосование

Comment: Насколько я знаю, намеренное снижение или наоборот повышение рейтинга одному конкретному пользователю, определяется автоматически в фоновом режиме и также автоматически откатывается системой. У Вас уже вроде все наладилось судя по текущему рейтингу...или нет?

Comment: Другой совет - исправить свои вопросы. На некоторых из них далеко не один минус, а это значит что это уже не случайность. Прочитайте справку, в частности [Как задавать вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Если чего-то не понимаете(почему какой-то конкретный вопрос заминусовали) - задайте вопрос в чате или на мете. Вам помогут определиться с правилами.

Comment: У Вас только один вопрос с одним минусом и одним плюсом. Остальные либо одни минусы, либо одни плюсы, либо ничего вообще. Поэтому говорить, о том что этот пользователь прошелся по всем абсолютно Вашим вопросам не приходится.

Comment: @МихаилРебров, но в любом случае кто-то прошелся по 5 вопросам и был откат :-)

Comment: хотя возможно их к этому моменту просто уже откатили

Comment: @Grundy, полностью согласен. Но в любом случае лучше подробнее ознакомиться с правилами.